# Do wings and tails count as limbs for Alter Self?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm creating a winged, tiefling, warlock, illusionist type character, but I've come across a possible hindrance. Although it won't matter until later, I've noticed that  Alter Self has a restriction that you can't change the amount of limbs you have. Do the wings and tail of tiefling count as limbs for that purpose?

I'm interested in knowing if *Alter Self* will be able to 'remove' my wings and tail.

The specific text is

> ...your basic shape stays the same; if you're bipedal, you can't use this spell to become quadrupedal, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wings: yes, Tail: no

A [limb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limb) is:

> one of the projecting paired appendages (such as wings) of an animal body used especially for movement and grasping but sometimes modified into sensory or sexual organs

However, for the purposes of Alter Self having 6 is an advantage. You can look like a six limbed creature which your quad limbed colleagues can’t and, if you want to look like a four or two limbed creature you can make the superfluous limbs vestigial and hide them with clothing.